# Run an application from the IIS application pool

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have a console application which basically sends emails once per day.

The Windows server administrator disallows this technique and doesn't want to allow extra software on the computer (launched by a scheduled task or a service).

I've been asked to evaluate the possibility of redeveloping a part of the application and integrate it into the IIS application pool but I don't think IIS can do this. Is it possible ? If so, how ?

The only approach I've looked at so far is to redevelop it as a web application and launch a web page everyday with a scheduled task, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: IIS is not well suited for this. Have you considered a windows service?

Comment: well he doesn't want to use a service. it wants to isolate the process into iis.

Comment: Your windows server administrator is horrible.  He'll let you install a custom web app but not a scheduled task or service which better suits the problem?  Ridiculous.

Comment: Maybe is a shared hosted environment or similar...

Comment: it is a server used by one application used by 3 customers. It is planned that there should be more application in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze your options:

1. Use **task scheduler** in your server to launch **console app**
2. Use **task schedule**r in your server to **web service hosted in IIS**
3. Have an **IIS application running 100% of time** in an infinite loop that that checks time every minute and if it happens to be the correct time send the emails
4. Have a **windows service**.
5. Use **task scheduler in a different server** to invoke

Analyzing each one of them:

1. KO: Your administrator does not want console apps and process is not isolated.
2. KO: You have process isolated but still you are installing a console app.
3. **OK**: Not very good for performance but your fulfills your admin conditions.
4. KO: Your admin does not want windows services.
5. **??**: Probably your admin will not want to use an extra server

**Proposed solution**: As you can see only options 3 and 5 might pass the filter. Ask him

**Correct solution** I did similar things in the past and went for option 2. You have to convince your admin that solution 3 is a bad idea and probably 5 is already out of the question. When he had to choose the lesser of the evils option 2 is the best :-)

NOTE: You don't mention it but in case you have a SQL Server or similar you can store there an scheduled task too...

Comment: well I talked to the admin, he agrees finally to add a code into a web page and call it from the task scheduler. thanks for your great answer

Comment: Good :). If I were you I would put it in a WCF webservice. And would make it robust enough to be able to survive classic errors like being invoked several times in a day resulting in several emails being sent (imagine that someone learn the url and send it thousands of times)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar questions when I was moving from Apache servers (where it's dead easy to send a nightly email) to Windows (where you have options).

Clients have sometimes pushed me towards SQL Mail.  It's not terrible.  If your web app has a SQL backend, and it's okay to schedule things there, it's capable of sending emails when properly configured.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.  With an IIS application you'd need something to trigger loading the application (call the web page).  This itself would require a scheduled task.

You need to pound some sense into your administrator.  Sorry.